# How to backup data from Realm DB of Live react native app

Tags: react-native, realm

I was using realm db for my react native app, but now I want to take a backup of data from that app which is live ( I don't have the codebase of it right now ). How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please add more context for the people trying to help you out. I would like to understand what the situation is. Is Realm used as a local database? Do you have access to the location where the data lives? I don't think this is enough information to get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I was using Realm as my local database to save data if device is offline, 
Im unable to access the data location.